# ReactJS Redux RxJS AJAX loading indicator

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, rxjs, rxjs-dom

I have a ReactJS & Redux application, and using RxJS for async AJAX with cancellation and error handling. The middleware (for Redux) I am using to connect Redux and RxJS is redux-observable.

I am having a request to the server which also handles errors and cancellation, this is the epic:

```
const RecipesEpic = action$ =>
action$.ofType(FETCH_RECIPES)
    .mergeMap(action => {
        return Observable.ajax({
            method: "get",
            url: url
        })
            .map(payload => {
                return ({ type: FETCH_RECIPES_FULFILLED, payload })
            })
            .catch(error => Observable.of({
                type: FETCH_RECIPES_REJECTED,
                payload: error
            }))
            .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_RECIPES_CANCELLED))
    })

export default RecipesEpic
```

**I'm trying to implement a loading indicator, first I want to log to the console how many percents completed of the request (by using XHR2), and then I will implement the UI. In simple words: How to implement XHR2 download progress in RxJS DOM Request?**

I didn't find any resources online about this question, and I hope other people who are searching for this question will have an answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to [The RxJS Ajax Documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md) you can supply a `progressObserver`  in your Observable.ajax call. The Observer you supply will be updated with the XHR2 download progress!

Comment: Cool! Can you show me how to use progressObserver() in code? I am also pretty new to XHR2.

Comment: Any help? Everyone? By the way, how do I also implement the XHR upload progress?

Comment: yeah, there is a bug in it at the moment. No work :(